# Are there any effects upon a proton an electron can impart when returning to its ground state after absorbing and emitting a photon?

Tags: atomic-physics, measurements

Basically the title. When an electron and proton are bound say within a hydrogen atom, are there any measurable effects upon the proton when its electron goes through the process of absorbing, obtaining a higher energy state, releasing an identical photon, and returning to its ground state?

Comment: The basic misconception in the question is "its electron goes through the process of absorbing". It is the whole atom that absorbs or emits.

Answer (score 2):

Electrons and protons are “indistinguishable particles.” Any proton is exactly the same as any other proton. A proton which has a history of interacting with some electrons cannot be distinguished from a proton with no such history; protons do not remember.

Within the context of a hydrogen atom, there are some transitions which cause the proton’s spin to flip.  (I can never remember whether a change in the nuclear spin is part of the “fine structure” or the “hyperfine structure” of an atom’s spectrum; I have to look it up every time.) Sometimes descriptions of the hydrogen atom include the quantum number for the electron spin projection but neglect the quantum number for the proton’s spin. In that approximation, you might say that a proton-spin-changing atomic transition has “affected” the proton.  But if your model doesn’t omit any quantum numbers, then atomic states with the same quantum numbers are *also* indistinguishable.

A very energetic electron can drive strong-interaction transitions inside the proton, such as $\rm p \to \Delta \to n\pi^+$ or $\rm p \to \Delta \to p\pi^0$. But if there is a proton in the final state of such an excitation, it can’t be distinguished from the initial proton. Protons don’t remember.

Comment: Nice answer. Fine structure is the splitting of the spectral lines due to electron spin and relativistic corrections to the Schrödinger equation, whereas _hyperfine structure_ is caused by the interaction between the electron's magnetic field and nuclear spin.

Comment: I probably mix them up because the hyperfine states, with nuclear-spin information, get quantum numbers traditionally called “$F$.” For the pedagogical level of this question, I’m comfortable leaving the text as “there is a name for this effect.” I appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The photon is not absorbed by the electron, but by the atom. The system "proton+ electron in fundamental state" becomes "proton + electron in excited state" by absorbing both the energy and the momentum of the photon, thus acquiring a nonzero speed. When the photon is re-emitted, the direction it is re-emitted need not be the same as the direction it had arrived. So the momentum of the atom need not become zero, and the atom back in its fundamental state might have kinetic energy. This is not in contradiction with energy conservation because the frequency of the emitted photon would be modified by the Doppler effect, and precisely because energy conservation is perfect, the Doppler-induced decrease of energy of the re-emitted photon compared to the initial one would be exactly the kinetic energy acquired by the atom.

So the answer to your question is : the whole atom, proton+electron will most probably have acquired some momentum and the associated kinetic energy, but otherwise will be unchanged.

However, in the case that maximizes the recoil, when the photon is re-emitted in the direction opposite to its arrival, the velocity of the atom (assuming it is initially static) will be only 6 meters per second, which is very small.